# Compiling error during using ant to release android package

Tags: java, android, ant

My Android project has two external libraries: A and B. Using Ant command line to compile the Android project, I encountered the error below. Library A's path is `D:\Workspace\library`.

I marked Project A as a library in project.properties file, which is the instruction from [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506525/android-datepicker-unexpected-top-level-exception-classes-jar-not-found). However, it still doesn't work out. Clearly the compiling treats Project A not as a library and requires the file of classes.dex.

Any more suggestions?

**Error:**

```
[dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into d:\apk\compile\classes.dex...
       [dx] 
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Workspace\library\bin\classes.jar (系统找不到指定的文件。)
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
       [dx] 
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Workspace\YimianBaseLib\bin\classes.jar (系统找不到指定的文件。)
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
       [dx] 2 errors; aborting
```

Comment: do you have any jar libs in app?? i strongly believe issue is with  jar library included in ur app

Comment: Yes. In either main project or lib project, there are a couple of jar libraries. Is there any solution to address the issue? Or any clue for the problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: ok check is there any repetition of jar and tell me how you add the files

Comment: Project A is a hybrid structure: two jars under libs folder and its own project needed to be connected with main project. One jar is android-support-v4.jar automatically imported by the system to support lower version, and the other is gson-2.2.4.jar manually imported to better pares JSON.

Comment: do you copy that fist to libs and added ? is any duplication?? any way check this http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/fix-the-conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-with-adt-14

Comment: Thanks! I added these two jars to the lib folder.(Actually I did it again and don't fix the problem) And I read that article from the url but don't find the same problem from our project.

Comment: @Sreekanth Thank you very much! Finally I worked it out. It's not a duplicate lib or import problem, but a problem of whether or not it is a lib project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause for this error is that the two lib projects are not treated as a library, although they two are clearly note as "android.library=true" in project.properties (I am quite puzzled here but quite sure that I do everything to tag it as a lib.) For Ant's compiling mechanism, it will make jar file with different name but with the same content based on whether or not it is a lib

1. For a non-library project, it will be ${project_name}.jar
2. For a library project, it will be classes.jar

Compiling the main project, Ant needs classes.jar as input for its dependencies to make final package. So the process stopped here. I have to use a stupid solution to fix it: post-release of lib projects, i renamed ${project_name}.jar to classes.jar and worked it out.